# How do I use PDO in PHP to get data out of a SQL Server DB and properly encode it in a UTF-8-encoded MySQL DB?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, pdo, utf-8

I'm using PDO in PHP to connect to a SQL Server DB and pull data out to essentially replicate the SQL Server DB in a MySQL DB.

After some searching, I found that the collation of the SQL Server DB is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, which equates to the ISO-8859-1 encoding. As such, when I connect to the SQL Server DB with PDO, I use the following:

```
$dsn = 'dblib:host=aws-rds-endpoint.rds.amazonaws.com:1433;dbname=db-name;charset=iso_1';
```

The `iso_1` on the end seems to properly pull everything out of the SQL Server DB without any garbled text.

The MySQL DB is UTF-8 though, so I run the following on each string value to convert everything from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8:

```
$val = isset($val) ? mb_convert_encoding($val, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1') : null;
```

However, when I insert the data into the MySQL DB (for which I've done the following for the DB link in PHP: `mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8');`), I am getting garbled text.
The following are some examples of garbled characters:

```
’ => PU2
“ => STS
” => CCH
```

The `PU2`, etc. show up in the MySQL DB with black boxes around them. (Please note that I'm using MySQL Workbench to connect to the MySQL DB.)

Basically, I don't know why it's garbling these characters or how to fix it. If I don't run the `mb_convert_encoding` function above, then when I insert the data into the MySQL DB, all the strings with characters like the above instantly get truncated at the first instance of a weird character and the truncated string is inserted into the MySQL DB.

As a final note, the fields that I've noticed this for in the SQL Server DB are all `nvarchar` with a `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH` of -1 and a `CHARACTER_SET_NAME` of `UNICODE`, not `iso_1`, in case that matters.

Comment: Basically you have to have an idea what your source encoding is. Then just put it in mysqli_set_charset();

Comment: Why would I want to put the source encoding into `mysqli_set_charset`? The basic process in my mind is to get the data out of the SQL Server DB with the correct encoding (ISO-8859-1, I believe), use `mb_convert_encoding` to convert it from the source encoding to the target encoding (UTF-8), and then have `mysqli_set_charset` set to UTF-8 so I can properly store it in a UTF-8 MySQL DB. Is that not right?

Comment: Also, I should note that when I do `mb_detect_encoding($val)`, I get back `false`, but if I do `mb_detect_encoding($val, 'UCS-2, UTF-8, UNICODE, ISO_1, ISO-8859-1')`, I get back `ISO-8859-1`.

Comment: then put latin1 in mysqli_set_charset

Comment: That totally worked!... but I'm confused why. If the MySQL DB is a utf8 collation, why would setting `mysqli_set_charset` to `latin1` work? I mean, it worked, and that's great, but would love to understand why. Thank you.

Comment: mysqli_set_charset() is not for telling a database which encoding it's using. A database knows it already. this function is to tell a database what encoding your source data is. then it will convert it internally

Comment: Well, that was a huge learn for me today. Thank you so much for clarifying that. It most definitely solved my problem. Would  you like to write that up an as answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use any conversion routines, it will only add to the confusion.

```
utf8 Hex latin1 hex  Unicode     Char    Name
E28099   92          8217=x2019  [’]     RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
E2809C   93          8220=x201C  [“]     LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
E2809D   94          8221=x201D  [”]     RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
```

These are valid `UTF-8` (outside MySQL) characters, and valid MySQL characters in both `ut8` and `utf8mb4` `CHARACTER SETs`.

The 8-bit latin1-utf8 mappings are [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#8_bit_encodings).

Most programming languages will not treat them as the same as apostrophe (`'`) and double quote (`"`).

This is good:

```
mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8');
```

But, do you also declare the column's `CHARACTER SET`?  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

I don't recognize `PU2`, etc.

**If you *correctly* tell MySQL what the client's encoding is (latin1, utf8, etc), then MySQL will *correctly* convert to the `CHARACTER SET` of the column you are putting the data in** (assuming a conversion is possible).  From the Comments, it sounds like the client used `latin1` (eg, `92`, not `E8099`).

Comment: Thanks, Rick James. Your Common Sense already helped me solve the problem. As he stated, `mysqli_set_charset` needed to be used to dictate the encoding of the data going into the MySQL DB, not the encoding of the DB/tables themselves.

Comment: And also the data coming back out.